# cucumber-jvm junit reports and maven-surefire-plugin

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm trying to figure out how to get [cucumber-jvm](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm) to produce separate xml report for each feature file. At this moment if I'm running it with **mvn** I'm getting a single xml, but I wan't a separate file for each.

For each feature file a descendant of [org.junit.runners.ParentRunner](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/ParentRunner.html) is being created. You can browse this code [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/junit/src/main/java/cucumber/junit).

Is it possible somehow to tell surefire to create a separate xml for each **runner**?

More info here: [#171](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/171)

Thank you, guys!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to split it with XSLT or other language? Sometimes is better to create an additional task in maven to run after the previous one. If the first XML contains all the data and is possible to split, I would tried it.